# Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 responsive Tables

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a responsive table using Boostrap 4 alpha 6. I tried using `<table class="table table-responsive">...</table>` as found in the docs, and the oldish way with a wrapper `<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table">...</table></div>`.

No luck so far. Anyone knows how to accomplish this?

Comment: What does "no luck so far" mean. What specifically is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a parent div which was not "contained" in the `flex` layout (did overflow it's parent).

So not specifically a problem with responsive tables but with flex child elements overflowing the parent.